# flutter statfulWidget refresh twice

Tags: flutter

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          key: _globalKey,
          onRefresh: refresh,
          child: Sub(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

there is simple refreshindicator and sub Widget

```dart
class Sub extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubState createState() => _SubState();
}

class _SubState extends State<Sub> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('sub');
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sub Widget print "sub" when it is built
the point is when i touch or just slightly drag page(not enough call refreshindicator) sub widget is rebuilt TWICE. i don't know why and i don't know how can i slove.
(statelesswidget can solve that problem but  i need to use statefulwidget)

Comment: Why are you using statefulwidget if it's just static data?

Comment: now i am using streambuilder so i need to use statefulwidget

Comment: I don't see initState but I guess you call refresh in it. You do not need it with RefreshIndicator

Comment: but i want page to move for user-interface

Comment: RefreshIndicator calls refresh by itself

Comment: i don't understand what you mean refreshindicator needs refresh fucntion so i added

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve without re-building but alternate I used was for flutter charts. Create a object `Sub sub1=Sub();` , somewhere outside `build()` or `intiState()` , then this widget will not rebuild again and values will be same.

Comment: i added Sub sub1 = Sub() in initState()  in parent Widget but the result was same.

Comment: did you added sub1 at top class like 
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          key: _globalKey,
          onRefresh: refresh,
          child: sub1,
        ),
      ),
    );